# Find PostgreSQL records with missing files on disc, and files on disc with missing DB records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am working with a PostgreSQL 9.6 read-only replica that I can't create functions or temporary tables in.

In one table there is a list of files that should be on disc. And in a directory on a completely different service there are the files themselves, named by file_id.

```
  Column   |   Type
-----------+-----------
 file_id   |  integer
 name      |  text
```

And on disc on another machine

```
ls -rt /var/www/dbfiles
519288     519290     519297     519298     519231     ...
```

There are about 5000 records and about 5000 files but I have reason to believe they don't match up. So I'm trying to find a way to run a query that will show which records in the DB don't have a file on disc, and which files on disc don't have a record in the DB. It's a one-off for now, so I don't mind a degree of hand-munging the directory listing.

If I could import the directory listing into a table, I would just do an outer join and look for nulls on each side. Is there a way I can outer join against a subquery full of IDs? Something like

```
SELECT f.name, dir_listing.id FROM files f
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT (519288, 519290, 519297, 519298, 519231...) AS id) AS dir_listing
```

where the output looks like

```
 name          |   id
---------------+---------
 myfile.txt    | 519288
 otherfile.txt | 
               | 519290
```

(etc)

Save me from CSV and VLOOKUP!

Comment: What is the problem with your output?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: That's just the output I was hoping to achieve. Your answer was perfect for my needs - thank you, and @a_horse_with_no_name too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `VALUES()`:

```
SELECT f.name, dir_listing.id
FROM files f FULL OUTER JOIN
     (VALUES (519288), (519290), (519297), (519298), (519231), 
     ) AS dir_listing (id)
     ON f.file_id = dir_listing.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works, you are just using the wrong syntax.

This expression:

```
SELECT (519288, 519290, 519297, 519298, 519231...)
```

returns a single row with a single column that is an anonymous record with a lot of fields.

What you can do is to list the IDs in a values clause (as known from the INSERT statement):

```
SELECT f.name, dir_listing.id 
FROM files f
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    values (519288), (519290), (519297), (519298), (519231), (...)
  ) AS dir_listing(id) on f.id = dir_listing.id;
```

Note that each value is enclosed in parentheses, creating on row for each value.

If you want a bit less typing, you could use an array constant that is unnested:

```
SELECT f.name, dir_listing.id 
FROM files f
  FULL JOIN unnest(array[519288, 519290, 519297, 519298, 519231...]) AS dir_listing(id) 
         on f.id = dir_listing.id;
```